# BigQuery SQL delete rows from a target table based on a condition

Tags: sql, merge, google-bigquery, delete-row

In BigQuery I need to delete all rows (one or more) in table A and insert one rows from table B only if value in table B is not null

Table A:

```
dateVal
2021-02-01
2021-02-10
```

Table B:

```
dataValNew
2021-02-05
```

Desiderated output:

Table A:

```
dateVal
2021-02-05
```

If table B is

```
dataValNew
null
```

Desiderated output is (nothing change):

Table A:

```
dateVal
2021-02-01
2021-02-10
```

I try using Merge. Something like:

```
MERGE A as t
USING B as s
ON FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND dataValNew is not null THEN
  DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND dataValNew is not null THEN
INSERT ROW
```

but dataValNew is not recognized because it's a field from source table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you'll have to resort to scripting:

```
DECLARE cnt INT64 DEFAULT 0;
SET cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE dataValNew is not NULL);
IF cnt > 0 THEN
  CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE A AS SELECT dataValNew as dataVal FROM B;
END IF;
```